# "What something is?" vs "what is something?"

Tags: questions, negation

I can write "what a cup is?" as question and I can write "what is a cup?".
Are both forms grammatically correct?

The former one looking a bit off when used without context, but I'm planning to use it in a pair like:
"What a cup is not?" and "What a cup is?". Stressing on IS rather than on a cup in this case, as I want to stress that definition is important and important when done in comparison to a not part.

Maybe it is sound even better with some adjective rather then noun, like:
"What flexibility is not?" vs "What flexibility is?".

But I feel that this is somehow wrong still.

Comment: "What a cup is?" is wrong.  That is not correct word order for an English question.  Only "What is a cup?" is the correct word order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Do you know where's Linda?" vs "Do you know where Linda is?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/do-you-know-wheres-linda-vs-do-you-know-where-linda-is) Also ["Do you know what IS IT?" vs "Do you know what IT IS?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/) and ["What's it say" VS "What is it saying" or "What it is saying"? Are the the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57195/), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, it adds some context into it. Thanks!

Comment: You're in good company. By my estimate, probably 99% of all non-native Anglophones struggle with this specific point!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Do you know what IS IT?" vs "Do you know what IT IS?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/do-you-know-what-is-it-vs-do-you-know-what-it-is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a cup? is a question form.

I can tell you what a cup is. is a statement form.

The question in writing always requires the inverted form.

Title: What a Cup Is and What It Is Not.

OR
What Is or Is not a Cup

Comment: Oh, yes. I completelly confused those. Thanks!